# Which iOS version to develop for new project?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios7

It's hard to find a reliable stats about iOS usage, and I don't know the changes in iOS 7 from development perspective, this is why I want to know for which version of iOS we should develop for new projects with worldwide audience target

Comment: What are your aims? Who is your audience? What is your app? How can we judge this for you??

Comment: iOS 7. Unless you have a special market that is going to be holding on to their older devices you should start with the latest and greatest. iOS 7 is on more devices than iOS 6 now anyway.

Comment: Well by following apples guidelines you should develop your app for iOS 7 first anyway and then if you **must** support iOS 6 then work backwards to make the app run on iOS 6... From our experience supporting both versions is a pain so you might even decide not to bother supporting 6 once you've written the app for 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mixpanel has [published their iOS version adoption data](https://mixpanel.com/trends/#report/ios_7).

Answer (score 0):

This is a good place to start: http://david-smith.org/iosversionstats/